# .NET Word library

Tags: asp.net, dll, ms-word

I am looking for a .NET Word library with the following specifications:

- Load a template document to replace text holders (`"[textToReplace]"`);
- Add tables on specified location (section, placeholder,...), allow continous rendering over multiple pages;
- Rendering to pdf
- Add images
- No Office automation

I have already found and tested Spire.doc ([Link](http://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/word-for-net-introduce.html))

Problems I have: rendering to pdf is not accurate (table only renders on new page, docx gives errors,...

Currently I am testing Aspose.Word ([Link](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx)), but my first test is already failing
(`doc.Range.Replace("[lblCompanyName]", "Bedrijfsnaam", False, True)` doesn't do anything). [edit: fixed this with doc.Range.Replace("[lblCompanyName]", "Bedrijfsnaam", False, False)]

Any other libraries available?

Comment: This type of question, asking for lists of things, belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com.  If you have a specific problem with a specific library that you want help with, that would go here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spire for this. Its a 3rd party component.